# Add new tab in cart page with form in Magento 2.4.4

Tags: cart, magento2.4.4, knockout

**I want to add a new Tab on the cart page with a custom form.**

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a checkout_cart_index.xml file in your module with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart.extra.tab"
                template="Infoicon_FreeShippingPromo::extratab.phtml" after="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        
</body>
</page>
```

2. Create a extratab.phtml file with below code

I am not able to add the phtml file code here so I am adding the screenshot
[image]

your tab would work here is the screenshot.

[image]

Please like if you find it useful. for form I have no idea what type of form you want to open, but through this phtml you can manage form as well.
Thanks